# Different colors in LED/LCD display when viewed from different angle?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I want to know why different colours appear when viewed with a different angle. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: At a fixed voltage, a particular single LED only emits one particular spectrum, see some examples https://www.google.cz/search?q=spectrum+led&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1317&bih=708 - You may want to be more specific about what you observe, it could have something to do with dispersion (like in rainbow), interference, absorption by a glass surrounding the diodes, reflection etc. etc. or you have some multi-colored diodes.

Comment: Do you mean an LED, or an LED/LCD display e.g. on a smartphone? LCD displays can change colour because they rely on the spacing of the liquid crystal molecules and this changes when viewed at an angle.

Answer (score 1):

if it is only a LED light,i guess the different color display you cannot distinguish that,because it is very tiny.
if you mean LED is a LED screen, that is because when the light pass through the surface,interference and reflection happened.
if you mean LED display cannot see it from 2 edge of side,that is because total reflection,so now people begin to develop new LED display,there has a technology called "moth eyes".